# What unit is "SetForce" on a revolute joint?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have not been able to determine the unit used for applying force to a joint with SetForce(). I assume that its argument is Torque [Nm] but I didn't find it in the documentation and must admit that the name of the method confuses me a bit?

Is there a reason why there is no SetTorque() method on joints?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20187/what-unit-is-%22setforce%22-on-a-revolute-joint?/) by [JakobWelner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5637/jakobwelner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From experiments, I can confirm that, for rotational joints, [`SetForce()'s`](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#ab2491053d1c5ebb97c377064797af494) `effort` argument is in **Nm** - at least with the ODE backend.

As to why it's SetForce() instead of SetTorque(), the [devs wanted to cover both rotational and prismatic joints](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5515/setting-force-to-joint-not-torque/).

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2413/alextoind/) on 2021-02-16**:
I believe that `N/m` is a typo for `Nm`, isn't it?

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) on 2021-03-30**:
Yep, good catch. Corrected it.